# Trusted host patterns problem, again

Tags: 9, configuration

I need to set up trusted host patterns for 3 EC2 instances. They all share same base code, so they all use the "same" settings.php.

On my two (production) instances everything works fine:

- examle-prod.test.io
- example-prod2.test.io

But on dev instance:

- example-dev.test.io

It just constantly keeps reporting info:

> The provided host name is not valid for this server.

Settings.php looks like this:

```
$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = [
  '^example-prod2\.test\.io$',
  '^example-prod\.test\.io$',
  '^example-dev\.test\.io$',
];
```

I already clear all the cache and done all the possible steps that I founded in documentation and forums, but nothing happens. The thing that worries me is that only on dev site I cannot do that, and soon we need to point another domain to production site so it is higly possible that the same thing will occure and I want to avoid that. Any suggestions?

Comment: What domain do you use to access the development site? What domain does Drupal see on that development site?

Comment: I'm using example-dev.test.io (of course with approprieted values but in that format) and Drupal see that domain, checked in HTTP_HOST before adding trusted_host_patterns in settings.php. I'm really not sure why on the other two domains it works ok, but here don't

Comment: The used regular expressions are correct, as per https://www.drupal.org/docs/getting-started/installing-drupal/trusted-host-settings. (PHP regular expressions would need a delimiter, but that is added by Drupal core.) I can only thing of two cases: The shown code is inside a comment, or the settings.php file is not the one used for the sites.